# Exclude some matches with sed

Tags: text-editing, sed

I have a series of files with entries(namespaces in source code) like

```
FW.WGS.Web.HHH.Controls, 
FW.WGS.Web.HHH.Email,  
FW.WGS.Web.HHH.Account, etc
```

and some with entries

```
FW.WGS.Web.Controls, 
FW.WGS.Web.Email,      
FW.WGS.Web.Account, etc
```

Using sed (or some other linux/unix tool) I want to change all FW.WGS.Web.Controls/Email/Account/etc for FW.WGS.Web.HHH.Control/Email/Account/etc.

My current sed command matches 's/WGS.Web/WGS.Web.\HHH/g' is not suitable - I end up with entries like

```
FW.WGS.Web.HHH.HHH.Email
```

So I need to prevent sed from matching lines that already have "HHH" in them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In sed, you can use `/pattern/!s/pattern/`, e.g.

```
/HHH/!s/WGS\.Web/WGS\.Web\.HHH/g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/WGS\.Web(?!\.HHH)/$&.HHH/g'
```

(where `$&` is a shortcut for the matched text)

See [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).