# Find and replace with exclude cases in sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to use `sed` to add a string after a certain pattern but I want to exclude the case where the additional string is already present.

For example:

```
"text.txt"

Hello
Bar
Hello world!
```

If I use `sed -i -e 's/Hello/Hello world!' text.txt` the third line becomes

`Hello world! world!`

but I would like to keep it intact.

I have found this [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/244723/exclude-some-matches-with-sed) but not all the lines in my file need to be modified.

Has anyone got recipe for this?

Comment: In fact, the related question gives you all you need. `/Hello world!/ !s/Hello/Hello world!/`

Comment: Ah thanks. Goodness me I couldn't make sense of this.

Comment: Please @choroba post it as an answer with a line of explanation so it can be accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your question is in kind of hidden in one of the answers in the related question:

```
/Hello world!/ ! s/Hello/Hello world!/
```

The first part of it is an "address", i.e. the following command only applies to lines matching it. The `!` negates the condition, i.e. the command will only be applied to lines *not* matching the address. So, in other words, *Replace `Hello` by `Hello world!` on lines that don't contain `Hello world!`*.

Comment: This might be more clearly put as `/Hello world!/! s/Hello/Hello world!/` (note the positioning of the `!`)... this way the negation is associated with the address, rather than with the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the explicit start and end of line anchors (`^` and `$`):

```
$ sed -e 's/^Hello$/Hello world!/' <<EOF
> Hello
> Bar
> Hello world!
> EOF
Hello world!
Bar
Hello world!
```

This could also be somewhat improved for readability / brevity by using `\0` which substitutes the whole match... This way you don't need to repeat the `Hello`:

```
$ sed -e 's/^Hello$/\0 world!/' <<EOF
> Hello
> Bar
> Hello world!
> EOF
Hello world!
Bar
Hello world!
```